# Figuring out if a number is an input in Java?

Tags: java

I made a program where I ask the user to input a number out of 0-8, and if it isn't a number a message will appear asking to input a number. If a letter is typed, on the next line it will say "please enter a number."

How do I do this? If it's more than 8 it stays 8 while if it is less than 0 it stays 0.

```
        if (number >= 8) {
            number = 8;
        } else if (number <= 0) {
            number = 0;
        }
```

---

UPDATE:

```
    System.out.println("Enter The Number you want:<0 - 8> "); 
    number = in.nextInt(); \\ in is the name of scanner 

    try {
      if number = in.nextInt(); 
      if(number >= 8) {
        number = 8;
      } else if (number <= 0) { 
        number = 0;
      }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Enter a number");
    }
```

This didn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look into [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), and see how it handles receiving something that is not a number.

Comment: Research.. try something.. if it doesn't work, come back for help with the code you attempted.

Comment: *** I did try the integer.parseint(String) method and the try catch method. I'll look into those links.

Comment: Perhaps using a third party library? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to read from the `System.in` and check if the string is a number:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    int i = sc.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
    System.out.println("not a number");
}
```

Comment: ' System.out.println("Enter The Number you want:<0 - 8> ");
 number = in.nextInt(); \\ in is the name of scanner
try 
{
if number = in.nextInt();
 
      
      if(number >= 8)
 {
            number = 8;
 }
 else if (number <= 0)
 {
     number = 0;
 }
 
     
}
    catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{
System.out.println("Enter a number");
}
'

When I tried running it the catch didn't work.

Comment: You should catch an `InputMismatchException`, not a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: `
 System.out.println("Enter The Number you want:<0 - 8> ");
 number = in.nextInt();
try {
number = in.nextInt();
      if(number >= 8)
 {
            number = 8;
 }
 else if (number <= 0)
 {
     number = 0;
 }

}    catch (InputMismatchException e) {

System.out.println("Enter a number please");
}`

Ran it again and the command line said "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException" etc.

Comment: Well, you're calling `in.nextInt` outside of the try-catch block. I don't even know why do you need two `in.nextInt` calls.

Comment: So I did the code that you provided from scratch again, and it worked thank you! But it didn't stop the program, the program should end right when the user inputs a letter when it should be a number. How do I do that?

Comment: Mate, you should read a couple of Java tutorials. Maybe read a book.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nigel Tufnel's answer, if you are not using Scanner (but BufferedReader instead, for instance), you can use the following:

```
System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
String numberString = in.readLine();
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
    System.out.println("You chose number " + number + "!");
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
}
```

Comment: I am using Scanner but thank you for answering.